# Update if variables exist else echo an error message?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make this script to where if it finds that the fname and lname do not exist that it will pop up a message saying that they never signed in.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("connect.php");
date_default_timezone_set("America/Winnipeg");
$date = ("m-d-Y");
$timeout = date("g:i:s a");
if ("SELECT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM signin_out
        WHERE   
            lname='" . $_POST['lastname'] . "'
            AND fname='" . $_POST['firstname'] . "'  
            AND date='" . $date . "')"
) {
    mysql_query("
        UPDATE signin_out
            SET timeout='" . $timeout . "' 
        WHERE
            lname='" . $_POST['lastname'] . "'
            AND fname='" . $_POST['firstname'] . "'
            AND timeout=''
    ");
    header("Location: ../index.html");
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript>'";
    echo "alert('<p>Oops! You never signed in!</p><br><p>Please contact a
                    Librarian</p>');'";
    echo "</script>'";
    header('Location: ../index.php?notsignedin');
}
?>
```

This is an intranet site for a highschool.

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: I prefer mysqli over pdo, but make sure you use one of these and it has nothing to do with Javascript

Comment: Your title says you want to check if a variable exists. What variable? The code looks like you're checking whether a record exists in the database -- is that what you really mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) signedin FROM signin_out
        WHERE lname = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']) . "'
        AND fname = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']) . "'
        AND date = '$date'";
$result mysql_query($sql) or die(myqsl_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['signedin'])) {
    // update table
} else {
    // Report not signed in
}
```

However, you really should switch to mysqli or PDO so you can use parametrized queries instead of concatenating strings, so you don't have to worry as much about escaping them.

Answer (score 0):

This is only one part of the answer, @Barmar gave u how to handle the query itself.

Change

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript>'";
echo "alert('<p>Oops! You never signed in!</p><br><p>Please contact a
        Librarian</p>');'";
    echo "</script>'";
header('Location: ../index.php?notsignedin');
```

To

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript>'";
echo "alert('Oops!\nYou never signed in!\nPlease contact a
        Librarian');'";
echo "window.location.href='../index.php?notsignedin';";
echo "</script>'";
```

The reason:
Strings which `echo` go into the web server buffer before being sent as a package to the browser.
This may cause your code to reach and do the `header` command, and then either you will redirect immediatly, or get an error message on the lines of '...you can not send headers after output...'

**And seriously consider everybody's suggestion about PDO/Mysqli and using a more centralized/abstracted way to use the DB.**

Answer (score 0):

Check how many rows are returned by the query,if is more than 1 then `fname` and `lname` exists in database,you can also use `count(*)` but i won't to change your query :

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM signin_out WHERE lname='".$_POST['lastname']."' AND fname='".$_POST['firstname']."' AND date='".$date);
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);//count number of rows returned by query
  if($num_rows >=1) { 

     //Update here

   }
  else {
    //alert and redirect here
  }
```

I understand that your site is for intranet use only , but i suggest to use `PDO` or `Mysqli`